# Purchased MacBook Pro a day after Yosemite release but got Mavericks instead

Tags: mac, macos, apple-store

I know they probably have stocks to finish, but I waited precisely one day after the presentation of Yosemite (October 16) to order my new Mac hoping it will come with Yosemite preinstalled.

Bummer, it came with Mavericks.

So what do I do next?

Comment: The [chat] rooms are a good place to ask surveys. If you have a practical problem you are trying to solve, feel free to edit this and it will be reviewed to remove the temporary hold.

Comment: Relevant answer linked below with info on historical Apple OS releases and the practices of getting the OS up to date on newly purchased Macs. - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100189/if-i-buy-a-mac-that-was-shipped-before-mavericks-was-released-will-it-have-mave/100192#100192

Comment: Thanks a lot, this settles my question. You could place this as an official answer so I can vote you up.

Comment: Do this: 1 Upgrade from Mavericks to Yosemite using the App Store. 2 Restart the computer and hold Command+R on the boot screen to enter Recovery Mode. 3 Use the disk utility to erase the contents of the hard drive. 4 Close the disk utility. 5 Install a fresh copy of Yosemite. This will download a fresh image of Yosemite and will install it on the empty disk. You will now have a Mac with a fresh copy of Yosemite just like you would get if you got it direct from Apple.

Comment: Interesting approach. Is there a source out there that explains this procedure, possibly in a more detailed fashion? I am kind of puzzled regarding point 3 (which parts of the SDD?) and point 5 (where do I find it and where shall it be saved if the SDD is empty?).

Answer (score 1):

Simple!

First you open the Mac App Store.
It should be the blue 'A' icon in your dock.
You can sign in by going to the Quick Links section at the side and click sign in.
Here you enter your Apple ID and password when prompted.

Then go to Updates at the top and OS X Yosemite should show up.
Then you click Free Upgrade and it should download and install.
Once it's finished installing you can open it and go through the procedures in the installer.